# Average value of input Data in Mitsubishi GX Works 2

Tags: plc, codesys

I need to obtain an average value of my input signals from mitsubishi input module Q64AD. I'm working in GX Works 2 in structured text.

This is how i used to obtain average value in Codesys:

```
timer_sr(IN:= NOT timer_sr.Q , PT:= T#5s );

SUM1:= SUM1 + napr1;
Nsum:=Nsum + 1;

IF timer_sr.Q THEN
    timer_sr(IN:= NOT timer_sr.Q , PT:= T#5s);
    outsr := SUM1 /Nsum;
    Nsum := 0;
    SUM1 := 0;
END_IF;
```

napr1 - is value from module

This piece of code is not working in GX Works 2, and i think because SUM1 is not an INT data type, but just a Word[signed] type.

Is there a way to make SUM1 an INT type or may be there is another logic to that solution?

Answer (score 0):

In other platforms it should work but the compiler gives a warning so I guess it will still compile? Of course, if the value is negative there will be problems.

You can convert a `WORD` to `INT` by the IEC function `WORD_TO_INT`. I'm not sure how well your system follows the standard but if it does, try the following:
`WORD_TO_INT(SUM1)`. If the SUM1 > 65535 then there will be problems as the upper bound of `INT`is 32767.

If this doesn't help, could you provide more details? How is it not workin?

Ps. The WORD is unsigned data type, not signed as you wrote.